# Can I say "Any number, including prime themselves, is composed of the addition of primes"?

Tags: prime-numbers

Since prime numbers are like irreducable blocks in the number system, can I say that:

"Any number, including prime themselves, is composed of the addition of primes?"

I have quickly checked for a few numbers up to 10 and could tell that it is True. I have also attached a picture to help with the explanation.

[image]

Comment: Every even number is the sum of some 2s, and every odd number (above 1) is the sum of a 3 and some 2s.

Comment: @bof , yes, that was my thought too, but since OP is very likely not a native speaker of English (and probably not of any other Indo-European language either), I think we should cut them some slack. (It did jar the sensibility.)

Comment: @YiXiangChong FYI, from [Complete sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_sequence#Other_complete_sequences), a related concept is that $1$, along with the set of primes, forms a "complete sequence", i.e., a set where "... every positive integer can be expressed as a sum of values in the sequence, using each value at most once".

Comment: @bof and Lubin. Thank you I have edited and improved the grammar from 'are' to 'is'